# nfs mount connection time out ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, mount, nfs

In Ubuntu 16.04, while attempting to mount with the following command:

```
'sudo busybox mount -t nfs ipaddress:/host_path/.nfs-mount /client_path -o nolock,tcp,rw'
```

The following error is returned

```
Connection timed out
Error attempting to ssh/run-ssh-command: exit status 255
```

I've tried checking to make sure the firewall wasn't effecting it, that the ports are open, i've added the nfvers=2/3 version flags...but can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong ( but suspect theres something off w/ my flags)